# Get fileName in jquery Upload plugin for append it in html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have an issue with my jquery upload plugin, I am using jQuery Upload File Plugin version: 3.1.10 from http://hayageek.com and the problem is with filename wich i want to copy it to database.

I have my html form little complex with `texts`, `checkboxes`, etc.

a part of my `form` looks like this:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="titlu" value="Marcel">
   <div id="incarcareImagine">Upload image</div>
   <button type="button" onclick="showValues()">Publish</button>        
</form>

        <script>
        function showValues() {
            var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
            $( "#results" ).html( str );
            var dataString = "results="+ str;
            $.post('motor/parser_incarcare.php',dataString,function(theResponse){
                //alert('data is sended to php'); //shows data to php response
            });
          }
        </script>
<script src="js/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            var settings = {
                url: "upload.php",
                method: "POST",
                allowedTypes:"jpg,png,jpeg",
                fileName: "myfile",
                multiple: false,
                onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr){}
            }
            $("#incarcareImagine").uploadFile(settings);


        });
    </script>
```

File upload plugin is here: https://rawgit.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/master/js/jquery.uploadfile.min.js

This script on succes of upload image is auto generating contet under `#incarcareImagine` like `1). the_name_of_the_uploaded_file.jpg` and the progress bar under this text.

My question is how to generate inside of the `<form>` an child like this: `<input type='hidden' name='image' value='the_name_of_the_uploaded_file.jpg'>`

My upload.php looks like:

```
$director_Img = "fisiere_pub/Img/";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile2"]))
{
          $ret2 = array();

$error =$_FILES["myfile2"]["error"];
{

        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile2"]['name'])) //single file
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile2"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile2"]["tmp_name"],$director_Img. $_FILES["myfile2"]["name"]);
        //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

        $ret2[$fileName]= $director_Img.$fileName;
    }
    else
    {
        $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile2"]['name']);
        for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
        {
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile2"]["name"][$i];
            $ret2[$fileName]= $director_Img.$fileName;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile2"]["tmp_name"][$i],$director_Img.$fileName );
        }

    }
}
echo json_encode($ret2);
 }
```

So in the end I will have my complete `form` and will be ready for sending this complete data via `ajax - serialize()` to my `php parser` for copy all wanted data to the `mysql database`

Thanks in advance team!

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you NEED to do that (can't you just get the name from the PHP side?) but if you really want to do it you could just add something along the lines of:

```
function showValues() {
    $("form").find("*[name=image]").remove();
    var field = $("<input type='hidden' name='image' value=''>");
    field.val($("form").find('input[type=file]').val());
    $("form").append(field);
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
```

Comment: Because in my database i want to make all records in one single query with one single ID, so this is an automated upload file script and when i drop a image over the script this will send her to php side for upload but when the upload process is completed, the others fields will be not ready for send to my final mysql query

Answer (score -1):

Since you are uploading to a PHP file, and processing it on a PHP backend, what we tend to do is accept the upload, after accepting the upload rename so that there are no conflicting filenames in the upload folder, then echo from the php back to the javascript.

```
function upload() {
    do_upload();  
    rename($file);
    echo $filename;
}
```

Then from the javascript callback `(xhr)` , you have access to the echoed name.

```
onSuccess: function( files, data, xhr ) {
   var filename = xhr.responseTxt // from php;
   var field = $("<input type='hidden' name='images[]' value=''>");
   field.val(filename);
   $("form").append(field);
}
```

This way you can then send the filename back to the php, and associate it in the database.

Comment: My upload.php is echo as json_encode() and i cant get the right filename.